# Pandas: how to compare a column to a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column with many different-sized lists.I would like to compare it with a second column preferably without expending a column_of_lists to multiple columns.

```
| value | column_of_lists |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | \[1,2,1,1\] |
| 3 | \[3\] |
| 1 | \[4,4\] |
| 3 | \[0\] |
```

to

| value | is_in_column_of_lists |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 3 | True |
| 1 | False |
| 3 | False |

I tried

```
df.loc[df['value'].isin(df['column_of_lists']), 'is_in_column_of_lists'] = True
```

but I got

| value | is_in_column_of_lists |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 1 | False |
| 3 | False |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `in` operator:

```
df['is_booked'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['value'] in x['column_of_lists'], axis=1)
```

---

```
   value column_of_lists  is_booked
0      1    [1, 2, 1, 1]       True
1      3             [3]       True
2      1          [4, 4]      False
3      3             [0]      False
```

Comment: Thank you . The answer turns out to be very simple lol